# What's family on a JWT refresh token rotation

Tags: oauth, jwt, access-token, refresh-token

I'm studying JWT Access Tokens (AC) and Refresh Tokens(RT) with rotation - that means for every renew RT request, application generates a new pair of RT and AC tokens.

I see some blogs, posts mentioning about JWT **token family** - usually when server identifies malicious RT on renew requests then the token family should be invalidated and a new one should be used.

**What's JWT token family and how to create them ?**

Nothing relates token family on RFC https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7519

Answer (score 1):

The JWT token family, in this sense, would be all the access tokens and refresh tokens that were created based on one concrete RT.

When you first perform the authorization code flow and authenticate the user, you will issue the first pair of AT/RT. All other tokens based on this initial RT will form the JWT family.

How to create such a family is up to you and it is not standardised. One solution would be to save all tokens in a database with a reference to the original token. This will allow you to revoke these tokens afterward. Another quite common solution is to create one entry in your database that represents the original act of issuing a token (sometimes called a "delegation"). Then, you can add a claim to all your tokens with the ID of that delegation. When you want to revoke tokens you can just mark the delegation as revoked.

Remember that revoking access tokens is much more tricky. The access token is validated by your APIs and is often done offline (when the token is something like a JWT). Now your APIs would have to contact the Authorization Server to check for access token revocation. That's why it's recommended to have short-lived access tokens so that you don't have to deal with revocation.

Comment: So the "family" in other words is somehow point all issued AC to a FIRST issued value - a RT or a "delegation". Could you provide some samples of how the AC, RT and delegation are linked with each other? Not code necessarily. @Michal Trojanowski

Comment: Usually, it will be an entry in a database with some generated ID. Then, that ID is used in tokens as a claim value. E.g., you save the delegation with ID 123 and some data (date of issuing, user ID, maybe client ID, etc.). Then in the access and refresh tokens you would have a claim: `"delegation_id": 123`